# How to have a transparent gradient over an Image in React Native iOS?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have been dealing with the a gradient rectangle over an Image that has a black and a transparent sides, I have been looking about a gradient object in react native and I didn't found, but there is a react-native module that does this, but the problem is that it does work in android the transparency, but in iOS, it doesn't work, it shows white in place of the transparent side

[image: transparent gradient]

and than I was looking about a native iOS solution, I did but it's a bit complex, and I can't implement in react native this the snippet

```
CAGradientLayer *gradientMask = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientMask.frame = self.imageView.bounds;
gradientMask.colors = @[(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor,
                    (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
self.imageView.layer.mask = gradientMask; <-- // looking for a way to achieve this in react native
```

this is my react native code

```
    <Image ref={r => this.image = r}  style={styles.container} source={require('../assets/default_profile_picture.jpg')}>
      <LinearGradient ref={r => this.gradiant = r} locations={[0, 1.0]}  colors={['rgba(0,0,0,0.00)', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.80)']} style={styles.linearGradient}>
      </LinearGradient>
    </Image>
```

I don't know how to pass `LinearGradient` to `Image` as a mask

Comment: actually I have came across a work arround to achieve the same results in iOS which, I had to edit the source `BVLinearGradient.m` I overrided the setter of `setColors` with a `self.gradientLayer.colors = @[(id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f/255.0f green:0.0f/255.0f blue:0.0f/255.0f alpha:0.80f].CGColor, (id)[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];`

Answer (score 4):

Try `positioning LinearGradient absolute` adding style to LinearGradient

```
 <Image ref={r => this.image = r}  style={styles.container} 
        source={require('../assets/default_profile_picture.jpg')}>
      <LinearGradient ref={r => this.gradiant = r} locations={[0, 1.0]}  colors= 
                    {['rgba(0,0,0,0.00)', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.80)']} 
                    style={styles.linearGradient}>
      </LinearGradient>
 </Image>
```

```
styles.linearGradient = {
 ...,
 position:'absolute',
 width:'100%',
 height:'100%'
}
```

Comment: The image component does not take children like this.

Comment: No, the Image component cannot take <LinearGradient> as a child. Nor any children for that matter.

Comment: But `<ImageBackground>` can

Answer (score 1):

Just set `opacity: 0.5` for `styles.linearGradient`

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [react-native-image-filter-kit](https://github.com/iyegoroff/react-native-image-filter-kit) library to achieve this:

```
import { Image } from 'react-native'
import {
  SrcOverComposition,
  LinearGradient
} from 'react-native-image-filter-kit'

const masked = (
  <SrcOverComposition
    resizeCanvasTo={'dstImage'}
    dstImage={
      <Image
        style={{ width: 320, height: 320 }}
        source={{ uri: 'https://una.im/CSSgram/img/cacti.jpg' }}
      />
    }
    srcResizeMode={{ width: 1, height: 0.5 }}
    srcAnchor={{ y: 0 }}
    srcImage={
      <LinearGradient
        start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
        end={{ x: 0, y: '100h' }}
        colors={['rgba(0,0,0,0.80)', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.00)']}
      />
    }
  />
)
```

Android:

[image: Android]

iOS:

[image: iOS]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

## if you are looking for this type of implementation

```
              <View
                style={{paddingVertical: 5}}>
                <Image
                  source={{
                    uri: BASE_UPLOAD_URI + item.postimage.large.url,
                  }}
                  style={{
                    width: '100%',
                    height: 200,
                    borderRadius: 7,
                  }}
                  resizeMode="cover"
                />
                <LinearGradient
                  colors={[
                    'black',
                    'white',
                    'white',
                    'white',
                    'white',
                    'white',
                    'white',
                    'black',
                  ]}
                  style={{
                    height: 210,
                    width: '100%',
                    position: 'absolute',
                    opacity: 0.2,
                    top: 0,
                    bottom: 0,
                  }}></LinearGradient>
              </View>
```

package installation
**npm i react-native-linear-gradient**