# How to create gradient transparent image in react-native android?

Tags: android, react-native

Is there any way to create a transparent gradient image with react-native on android? I have an image and I want set gradient transparent on it like below image:

[image]

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097220/how-to-have-a-transparent-gradient-over-an-image-in-react-native-ios) and this [library](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient) but that not my answer.

Comment: cant open link of your image. try to upload to other website and share the link

Comment: @Berke I think you should use vpn

Comment: oh ok yeah I  see now.. Well it looks not so possible but maybe you could try to use one image as ImageBackground and place second image inside of it. ImageBackground could be gradient image and second one is that butterfly.

Comment: @Berke but in android is possible. Thanks for your solution but with that image didn't transparent correctly.